# Is it possible to use Prisma with Vitess

Tags: prisma, vitess

I heard recently about how Planetscale which uses Vitess can be used with Prisma.  At the moment I am using Postgres but would like to try out Vitess if possible.  Some of my searches found that Prisma is tested against Vitess (https://github.com/prisma/prisma-engines/blob/c28057e8dafb64a3b980d1f816494b183d47cf52/docker-compose.yml) but I can't find any docs saying if its possible and how to get it working.  Any help or direction would be greately appreciated.

Thanks

Paul

Comment: It should work out of the box with Vitess, using the `planetScale` preview feature. I'm assuming you have that as you're using Postgres.

Comment: Thanks Ryan! This is the only mention I could find of the "planetScaleMode" preview feature: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/7294  Do you know if there is anything more official?

Comment: Not at the moment. You would need to use it with `planetScaleMode` preview feature enabled.